# React router have issues on action in children routes react-router-dom@v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I have little environment in nodejs with mongodb and express-session, i follow react router tutorial https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial , and it's fine. But when i decide to make two children from layour route with two different actions like register and login on different submit the same action is throw. I can't find anything to solve it. Why on different action children my app read the same action for both?

APP.JSX FILE

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Register, { registerAction } from './component/Register';
import Login, { loginRequest } from './component/Login';
import Simplejs, {loader as isAuthLoader } from './component/SimpleJs';
import Layout from './component/Layout';
import ErrorPage from './component/ErrorLayout';


const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path:"",
        element: <Login />,
        action: loginRequest,
      },
      {
        path: "",
        element: <Register />,
        action:  registerAction,
      },
    ]
  },{
    path:"/index",
    element: <Simplejs />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: isAuthLoader,
    children: [

    ]
  }
], {basename: "/"});

function App() {
  return (
    <section>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </section>
  );
}
```

REGISTER ACTION:

```
export async function registerAction({ request }){
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const updates = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    await Registration(updates);
}
```

REGISTRATION HANDLER:

```
export const Registration = async (object) => {
    console.log('Registration');
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'include'
    }
    const body= object;
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/registration', body, config)
        console.log(res);
        const data = res.data
        if(data) return {data}
    } catch (error) {
        if(error.response.data.msg){
            console.log(error.response.data.msg);
        }else if(error){
            console.log(error)
        }else{
            console.log('errore');
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

LOGIN ACTION:

```
export async function loginRequest({ request }){
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const updates = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    await LoginAccess(updates);
}
```

LOGIN HANDLER:

```
export const LoginAccess = async (object) => {
    console.log('Login');
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'include'
    }
    const body= object;
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/login', body, config)
        console.log(res);
        const data = res.data
        if(data) return {data}
    } catch (error) {
        if(error.response.data.msg){
            console.log(error.response.data.msg);
        }else if(error){
            console.log(error)
        }else{
            console.log('errore');
            console.log(error);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: For some reson in react devtools i have this: 
action :ƒ loginRequest() {}
action: ƒ registerAction() {}

Comment: You can't have two routes trying to render on the same path. Perhaps you meant to have `"/login"` and `"/register"` routes?

Comment: Yes i want to have two different form on same child route with two different actions like register and login but without go to /login or /register url. Both need to be on /index url can it be?

Comment: Possible, yes, but not from the routes configuration part. AFAIK, you'll need one route and one component.

Comment: Thank you Drew, for everyone who will read this to use different action function on same child route just make in app.jsx for every child route path="register" without slash while in form action="/register" this don't redirect from index layout.